# How do I make a PDF link in HTML non-downloadable?

Tags: html, pdf

How do I not show the PDF toolbar in the browser when I open a PDF? More specifically, I don't want users to be able to download the PDF. My goal is to not show this: 
[image: Edge Toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a PDF non-downloadable is as simple as adding `#toolbar=0` to the URL.

To embed a PDF in your site:

```
<iframe src="doc.pdf#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

To open the PDF in a new tab:

```
<a href="doc.pdf#toolbar=0">PDF</a>
```

WARNING: This is not a DRM solution, a sophisticated user could still download the file from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really rely on the native browser viewer to prevent the download of the PDF. The only way to control the user experience fully is to replace the native viewer.

Adobe has recently released a client-side JavaScript viewer that will allow you to prevent download of the PDF. The relevant code is below but you can see a full working example at CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/practicalPDF/pen/WNQBLJV). See the last JSON object where the view parameters are set. Setting the "showDownloadPDF" property to false prevents the display of a download button. In this example, I've also prevented printing since the PDF can be recreated via print.

```
var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({
    clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    divId: "adobe-dc-view"
});
adobeDCView.previewFile(
    {
        content: { promise: Promise.resolve(blob.arrayBuffer()) },
        metaData: { fileName: "MyDocument.pdf" }
    },
    {
        embedMode: "FULL_WINDOW",
        defaultViewMode: "FIT_WIDTH",
        showDownloadPDF: false,
        showPrintPDF: false,
        showLeftHandPanel: true,
        showAnnotationTools: false
    }
);
```

Comment: This doesnt work. The IDM still download the PDF file.